# Falling into a catch clause in CIL

Tags: c#, cil

For a try block in CIL, I'm aware that you can enter a catch handler by throwing an exception in the protected block such as:

```
try {
     newobj Exception
     throw
     leave EX1
} catch {
     pop
     ldstr "catchblock"
     call WriteLine
} finally {
     ldstr "finallyblock"
     call WriteLine
}

EX1:
```

the throw statement will transfer control to the catch clause, which 
pops off the exception.

My concern(/curiosity) is whether this could be optimized so execution goes 
to the catch block not through a throw, but by "falling" into it via increment the PC. Something like this:

```
try {
     newobj Exception
} catch {
     pop
     ldstr "catchblock"
     call WriteLine
} finally {
     ldstr "finallyblock"
     call WriteLine
}

EX1:
```

Is this valid CIL? Is it possible to get to a catch handler block without using a throw statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's explicitly invalid.

In ECMA-335 Partition I, Section 12.4.2.8.1:

> Entry to filters or handlers can only be accomplished through the CLI exception system; that is, it is not valid for control to fall through into such blocks. This means filters and handlers cannot appear at the beginning of a method, or immediately following any instruction that can cause control flow to fall through.

Comment: my understanding of this is that you can't fall through to the handler, but the `leave` instruction may be omitted, just that control falls to the end of the try block, right ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm not sure that's possible? The last instruction can't be a branch by the branching source rules defined in the spec. So the last instruction HAS to be a leave. I think...

Comment: Thank you very much Brian, this is very beautiful news

Comment: @Titan, a couple of paragraphs below the quoted text in the spec, is the line "Exit from protected blocks, filters, or handlers cannot be accomplished via fall through."

Comment: Yeah there's a whole page of falling through in protected blocks in the CIL spec - kinda makes me annoyed I asked this question!